# Is there a latency guarantee on when events show up in the API using Fuel SDK?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, fuel-sdk

I am retrieving sends, opens, and clicks from the SendEvents, OpenEvents, and ClickEvents objects, and I'm wondering how long after real-time a time period should be available for pulling.

For example, immediately after sending an email, the send will not show up by doing a GET on SentEvents. But if I wait 30 minutes, then it will. Is there some sort of time bound on how long I have to wait for a time period to have all its events in there?

Comment: Please, this is such a simple question and it's very important for me to know, so I can safely pull time periods of data without worrying if it's actually all the data or not.

Comment: Tscizzle some questions may not be known by the community or be documented publicly. If you get no response you could try to go through Marketing Cloud/ support or your account executive.

Comment: How are you initiating the send?  If you are initiating it through the API, are you checking (Retrieve on the Send object) to determine that the Send.Status = Complete before attempting to retrieve SentEvent?